# AWS GP2 Disk Full But Shows Available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, diskspace

I am suddenly getting disk space errors across a lot of my web servers. They all use 20gb gp2 volumes. I checked a lot of the servers and they all show available disk space. These servers all run the same web app but serve different clients/traffic (so web logs are going to be different in volume). So it doesn't make sense for a lot of these servers to hit disk space limits at the same time.

It's almost like the EC2s are retaining deleted space even though it's showing disk available on /dev/xvda1. Increasing the volume by a few GB seems to give me some more available but I have rotated logs that I delete and thats not a long term solution. I have even tried to clear some web logs to help.

Is it possible the underlaying web server on AWS is hitting disk space limits?  Doesn't sound plausible to me and nothing in the status page. Any ideas what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a inode problem. Cleaned some folders up and it's fine now.